# scatter plot and line in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a question about how to place scatter plot and line into one graph correctly.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t= np.linspace(60, 180,100)
ax= plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data.Weight, data.Height , color = 'red')
ax.plot(t, 60+ 0.05*t, label=r"$Height = 60+ 0.05*Weight$")
ax.plot(t, 50+ 0.16*t, label=r"$Height = 50+ 0.16*Weight$")
ax.set_xlabel(r'$Weight$', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Height$', fontsize=12)
ax.set_title('Dependence')

plt.show()
```

[image]

As it can be seen scatter plot reflecting is not correct(it displays as lines)

Comment: The differences in line and marker options is explained in [basic matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py). I suggest spending some time with these tutorials and looking through the [example gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html) if you can adapt code similar to your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the variable `data` to be displayed in the scatter plot,

```
ax.scatter(data.Weight, data.Height , color = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

To scatter `data.Weight` against `data.Height`:

```
ax.plot(data.Weight, data.Height , 'o', markerfacecolor = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

These CSV files were downloaded from the kaggle weather data and it shows how to plot a scatter plot and a line plot added with a fill_between : the image is attached [image]

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

with open('antigua.csv') as antigua_data :
    reader = csv.reader(antigua_data)
    column_head= next(reader)


    for index,column in enumerate(column_head) :
        print(index,column)

    antigua_temperature = []

    for antigua_temp in reader :
        daily_temp = float(antigua_temp[10])
        antigua_temperature.append(daily_temp)


with open('antigua.csv') as antigua_data:
    reader = csv.reader(antigua_data)
    column_head = next(reader)


    dates = []

    for days in reader :
        date = datetime.strptime(days[3],'%Y-%m-%d')
        dates.append(date)

with open('train.csv') as antigua_data :
    reader = csv.reader(antigua_data)
    column_head= next(reader)

    afghan_temperature =[]

    for afghan_temp in reader :
        day_temp = float(afghan_temp[10])
        afghan_temperature.append(day_temp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(dates,antigua_temperature,c='red',alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(dates,antigua_temperature)
ax.scatter(dates,afghan_temperature)
ax.plot(dates,afghan_temperature,c='blue',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(dates, antigua_temperature, afghan_temperature, facecolor='red', alpha=0.1)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.set_xlabel('Dates')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax.set_title(f'A Comparison of Afghanistan weather and antigua')

plt.show()
```